# Start writing embedded code

Tags: embedded

I would like to learn how to write embedded code. Unfortunately, I am not very experienced programmer, and I haven't got a clue on how to start.

The project I'm working on is a PCB with a movement sensor and a microprocessor, and I want to control the settings of the sensor by programming the microprocessor.

What kind of hardware and software do I need? I have read that I need a [JTAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Test_Action_Group)/development board and a programming environtment. I would be glad for a reference to any book/website that would tell me (preferrably as basic as possible) on how to get started. So far I have found only sources that are not readable for me as a beginner.

The microcontroller ([STM32F101RC](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1169/SS1031/LN1567/PF164498), Core: ARM 32-bit Cortex™-M3 CPU) communicates with the sensor using [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus). The PCB contains both a USB and a JTAG connection (10 pins). Also, I'm using a Windows laptop to do the programming.

Comment: It really depends on exactly what processor you have, what interfaces there are on the board, and what development platform you are using - can you add more detail ?

Comment: Any interfaces on the board ? USB ? Ethernet ? JTAG ? Serial ?

Comment: had any thoughts of running some kind of operating system on your boards?  This will greatly influence your choice of tools

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what particular configuration you have - probably it's an ARM or AVR board. In both cases, you can grab a GCC-based (GNU) toolchain and start writing your C/C++ code as you would normally do - you just won't be able to use features which require an OS (i. e. file operations, using standard I/O - you have ports and SFRs instead), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Toolchain:

- Software: I recommend [Yagarto](http://www.yagarto.de) for a smooth start.
- Hardware: you will need an on-chip debugger. I do recommend [J-Link ECU](http://www.segger.com/cms/j-link-edu.html)

You may/should:

- Acquire at least quite some knowledge on embedded software/hardware (the book *[AVR Microcontroller and Embedded Systems: Using Assembly and C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0138003319)* is great!)
- Understand the basics of the [ARM Cortex-M3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Cortex-M3) architecture (google it! There are many resources, books, etc. there)
- Acquire some C experience
- Consider usage of [RTOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) if your product actually needs one.
- Take a look on [CMSIS](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-m/cortex-microcontroller-software-interface-standard.php) if you are going to use ARM Cortex-M3.
- Check you chip manufacturer if they provides any software libraries, bootloaders,... for the chip.
- Not doing a custom PCB at first, use a development board to prototype your project

Important note:

I don't know the criteria you chose the target processor on, but consider using an AVR 8-bit [microcontroller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller) if the project don't need the ARM M3 (32-bit) processing power. AVR is much easier and cheaper to start with especially for beginners. The rule here is to not use a microcontroller with capabilities that are too much higher than your product/project needs.

Answer (score 1):

To learn embedded systems programming , it is better to start with a simple 8 bit board and free ide. u may start with avr / 8051 family /pic family etc
the main problem with embedded programming is setting up the startup configuration / initialization suitable to your board features. if u start with your own board it will be difficult to cross this stage on your own. If you start with a readily available kit , then the given examples will walk u through this process easily. once u cross this stage u will gain enough confidence to handle bigger things. I am not advocating any one processor family here. One more thing is to be a good embedded programmer, one has to be fairly familiar with hardware also. In bigger projects where multiple team members work on an embedded project , u could get roles involving pure c and logic w/o much h/w knowledge , but to be versatile u have to be familiar how the board is designed how it is supposed to work.